# Hibernate OneToMany does not work on server

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-mapping, java-10, hibernate-onetomany

We try to implement a simple OneToMany connection between two Hibernate models. The first Model looks like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "proposals_item")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "item_id")
public class ProposalsModuleItem extends ModuleItem {

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "proposalsModuleItem", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Profiler> profilers = new HashSet<>();

}
```

The Second one like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "profiler")
public class Profiler {

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "proposals_item_id", nullable = false)
    protected ProposalsModuleItem proposalsModuleItem;

}
```

If I run my program locally with a local database, everything works fine. If I run the same thing on the server the connection does not work. ProposalsModuleItem.getProfilers() is empty.

I thought about something wrong in the database but I imported the server database into my local system and it still works.

I thought about something different in the database configuration. Locally I'm running on MySQL 5.7, on the server we are running an AWS Aurora. Maybe also important: We are running Java 10.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you use the right dialect for your online database?

Comment: We are using org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect. Should be the right one.